# Compiling java from python

Tags: java, python, compilation, javac

I'm writing a script to compile a .java file from within python
But the error

```
import subprocess
def compile_java(java_file):
    cmd = 'javac ' + java_file 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

compile_java("Test.java")
```

Error:

```
javac is not recognized as an internal or external command windows 7
```

I know how to fix the problem for CMD on windows. But how do I solve it for python?
What I mean is: how do i set the path?

Comment: Are you sure javac is actually on your Windows PATH? That's likely what it's using

Comment: Instead of setting the `PATH`, why not simply provide the absolute path of `javac` (or `javac.exe` in your case)?

Comment: You can try os.environ['PATH'] = PathToJava and see if that works.  It works on Linux but I've never tried on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, env = {'PATH': '/path/to/javac'})
```

or

```
cmd = '/path/to/javac/javac ' + java_file 
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: you _really_ don't need `shell=True`, just pass the arguments as a `list`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre He may need that for other env setup we don't know about; it was in the question so I left it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send arguments as well:

```
            variableNamePython = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "lib/JavaTest.jar", variable1, variable2, variable3], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            JavaVariableReturned = variableNamePython.stdout.read()
            print "The Variable Returned by Java is: " + JavaVariableReturned
```

The Java code to receive these variables will look like:

```
public class JavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String variable1 = args[0];
        String variable2 = args[1];
        String variable3 = args[2];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you change your example so it applies to the problem at hand, i.e. invoking `javac Test.java` instead of `java -jar lib/JavaMail.jar`?